# pandas.to_datetime gives OutOfBoundsDatetime Error

Tags: pandas

I have data in some format which I want to read into a pandas.DataFrame.
Some rows give me an error. Below is a minimal example for one of those strings, but i have several where it does not work (and strangely enough some where it does work).

The exact error is:

> OutOfBoundsDatetime, Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2276-02-18
>   05:15:13

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.to_datetime('02/18/2276 5:15:13 AM', format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

I used this site to make my format-string:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.strftime.html

I appreciate any help!

Comment: btw, to turn those dates into `NaT` use the keyword argument `errors=coerce`then the parsing just runs. I was having similar issues with a 9999/12/31

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is out of bounds because the `datetime` dtype is `datetime64[ns]` which has an upper bound limit of year 2262 see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units) if you change the resolution to a lower resolution then it can handle this datetime but you can't do this within `pandas` unfortunately. As `datetime`s are stored natively as `datetime64[ns]`, you'd have to do this within numpy or using a normal datetime.

Another method is to store the year in a separate column if it's outside of the bounds and set the year value to `1900` or some other indicator that the year is out of bounds.

However, this has performance issues as you lost some vectorised operations

Comment: Do you know why pandas is not able to handle granularity on day level? Could this be a feature request?

Comment: I think so, by default the dtype is `np.datetime64[ns]` I couldn't force it to something like `np.datetime64[D]`, it's possible to store `datetime.datetime` but you have latent issues when you try any conversion

Comment: I was neither. I'll check if there is a feature request. This could also work nicely together with `dt.floor('D')`or so.

Comment: thank you so much, I wasn't aware of this upper year limit! will work around that :)

Comment: This is a tricky problem, I think this should be a feature request on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) as it's a known limitation. Good luck