# Why is Python pandas limited to numpy.datetime64[ns]?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime, astropy

pandas use of numpy.datetime64[ns] (datetime measured in nanoseconds, 10^-9 s) limits date (yyyy-mm-dd) from 1677-09-21 to 2262-04-11 and pushes to use either **Python** **datetime** library for AD dates or **numpy.datetime[D]** or **Astropy** for *astronomical datetimes and julian days*. Are stock trades performed on [ns] basis?

```py
# numpy.datetime[D] (unit='D') is not recognized
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(arg=(-753, 4, 21), yearfirst=True, unit='D')
# returns
DatetimeIndex(['1967-12-10', '1970-01-05', '1970-01-22'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383367/pandas-to-datetime-gives-outofboundsdatetime-error

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html mistakenly writes about "If ‘julian’, unit must be ‘D’, and origin is set to beginning of Julian Calendar. Julian day number 0 is assigned to the day starting at noon on January 1, 4713 BC."

Comment: What exactly is the question here; i.e. what do you want to do which doesn't work? At the moment, this seems like multiple questions in one, + comments.

Comment: I am asking "why pandas uses only numpy.datetime64[ns]?" in datetime objects.

Comment: well, I can read that, but still, your motivation remains unclear to me.

Comment: Probably because it's just the most accurate format that can fit in a 64-bit machine integer, which should be good enough for the vast majority of practical purposes. Any other format is more complicated and less efficient to work with without specialized libraries.

Comment: I meant that numpy.datetime64[ms] or numpy.datetime64[us] would allow to use much greater range of dates up to 2.9e8 BC or 290301 BC. But only numpy.datetime64[ns] is implemented in pandas.to_datetime().